# How to get enum from byte

Tags: java, enums, byte

I am created an enum with the following code:

```
public enum Operation {
    a('0'), b('1');
}
```

After which I have byte 0 or 1.

Now I need a static class in this enum to get the appropriate enum from a byte:

```
    public static Operation fromValue(byte value){ ...}
```

How I can do this ?

Comment: `Operation.values()[value]` is probably the simplest way to do it, if not necessarily the most efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public static Operation fromValue(byte value) {
  switch (value) {
  case 0:  return Operation.a;
  case 1:  return Operation.b;
  default: throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hardcoding a switch as aix is doing, you can also go for the automatic variant to make sure everything stays in sync. Obviously we can optimize this by creating a `HashMap<Byte, Operation>` (you can initialize that in a static block or in the single constructors) but for your usual enum the following should do:

```
public static Operation fromValue(byte b) {
    for (Operation op : values()) {
        if (op.b == b) return op;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a static field in your enum containing the opposite mapping:

```
static Hashtable<byte, Operation> byteToOperation = new Hashtable<byte, Operation>();
```

And change the constructor of your enum to do `byteToOperation.put(byteValue, this)`

Then create a static function in you enum to get the Operation from this map:

```
public static Operation fromValue(byte value) {
    return byteToOperation.get(value);
}
```

That way:

```
Operation.fromValue('0'); //returns Operation.a
Operation.fromValue('1'); //returns Operation.b
```

And everytime you will add an element in the enum, it will be automatically added in the map.